# SsrsMsbuildTasks - Report image added using AddResource tasks renders as broken link in the report

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, msbuild

I'm using the following to add images during report deployment. The images are uploaded, and are valid (you can display them in the browser), but they are rendered as broken links in the reports.

```
<Target Name="AddResources" DependsOnTargets="ValidateDeploymentSettings;GetServerUrl">
    <AddResource ReportServerURL="$(TargetServerUrl)" Folder="$(TargetReportFolder)" 
        Files="%(ResourceFiles.Fullpath)" />
</Target>
```

Are there other parameters needed by AddResource task to make images work? Could this be a permission issue?

Any help appreciate.

Best,
/jhd
John Dhom

note: also posted to project forum here... http://ssrsmsbuildtasks.codeplex.com/discussions/274252

Answer (score 0):

AddResource will add the mimetype if you pass the pass the files using '@', as in...

```
<AddResource ReportServerURL="$(TargetServerUrl)" Folder="$(TargetReportFolder)" Files="@(ResourceFiles)" />
```